# Using @ViewChild without using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular

The project I work in uses Angular 8 but **not** TypeScript. I need to access a child component form from the parent, to check if its valid, which would normaly achieved by using `@ViewChild` like follows:

```js
  @ViewChild(Child)
  set appShark(directive: Child) {
    this.form = directive.form;
  };
```

Unfortunately I am unsure how to achieve the same thing using vanilla JS and not typescript. I know this is an odd question, and the simplest solution would be to use typescript but unfortunately that is not an option.

Comment: Angular 8 but not TypeScript? Angular 2+ is built upon TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer the behaviour of @ViewChild can be used in javascript without decorators by doing something like follows:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(){}

  activate() {
    this.views.activate();
  }
}

ParentComponent.annotations = [
  new Component({
    selector: 'hero-queries',
    template: `
      <view-child>
        <content-child></content-child>
      </view-child>
    `,
    queries: {
      view: new ViewChild(ViewChildComponent)
    }
  })
];
```

For anyone interested there is a handy cookbook for angular v2 and above in JS instead of typescript: [Cookbook](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is not possible, **Angular 2 + works ONLY with TypeScript**, so you can't use it without it, that doesn't make sense.

(In comparison, it's like asking how to use React without any JavaScript)